# redefining std::vector passed by reference (munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer)

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I just realized the potential danger of not doing a .resize on a vector passed by reference (I use c++ 11).
In the past I often would just reassign the vector, here 'todecompress' passed by reference with the call below, but this seems to lead to memory freeing issues. Especially in this case where the reassigned vector is of larger size than the original.
Could you please explicit what exactly is happening here and why it is wrong. Is a .resize (possibly followed by a value initialization) the correct way?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void compresszeros(std::vector<int>& tocompress)
{
    int len = tocompress.size();
    
    int i = 0, ci = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        if (tocompress[i] > 0)
        {
            tocompress[ci] = tocompress[i];
            i++; ci++;
        }
        else
        {
            int cntconsec = 0;
            while (i < len && tocompress[i] == 0)
            {
                cntconsec++;
                i++;
            }
            tocompress[ci] = -cntconsec;
            ci++;
        }
    }
    
    tocompress.resize(ci+1);
    tocompress[ci] = len;
}

void decompresszeros(std::vector<int>& todecompress)
{
    std::vector<int> tdc = todecompress;
    
    int len = todecompress.size();
    int dlen = todecompress[len-1];

    todecompress = std::vector<int>(dlen, 0);

    int di = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (tdc[i] > 0) // there are no 0 values in the compressed vector
        {
            todecompress[di] = tdc[i];
            di++;
        }
        else
            di += std::abs(tdc[i]);
    }
}

void printvector(std::vector<int> input)
{
    std::cout << "Vector size is " << input.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        std::cout << input[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{   
    std::vector<int> tocompress(50,0);
    printvector(tocompress);
    
    compresszeros(tocompress);
    decompresszeros(tocompress);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Extract and provide a [mcve] where this alleged "memory freeing issues" occur. Please also read [ask] as it's unclear what code you're referring to. Keep in ming we only know what you wrote here about your problem! As a new user here, also take the [tour] if you haven't already.

Comment: no you should not need to resize when afterwards you assign a different vector anyhow. Please post code that demonstrates the issue of "but this seems to lead to memory freeing issues".

Comment: you are accessing `tocompress[ci]` without making sure that `ci` is a valid index and only afterwards you call `tocompress.resize(ci+1);`. That might be a problem

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 When I remove the myalgorithm:: namespace calls and put the compress/decompress fcts above the main it compiles... but it also does not lead to the error anymore. So you are saying I can just redefine the reference vector with an assignment to = std::vector<int>(...); ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks for the help. In this case however I have the guarantee that ci is always <= i, so it will always lead to valid calls.

Comment: what you describe sounds like undefined behaivor somewhere. I would bet on an out-of-bounds access, because most of your accesses are unchecked. Using `at` instead of `[]` would be the quick way to check that, but I rather suggest to add explicit checks in the code instead of relying on your logic being correct. Maybe it is correct, but a `if (ci >= tocompress.size())` would help a lot while reading the code

Comment: " When I remove the myalgorithm:: namespace calls and put the compress/decompress fcts above the main it compiles..."  when is that easy to make the code compile you should post the code that does compile. If you post code that needs to be modified to be compiled then we cannot tell you what is the problem in your code, we can only look at an error in our modified code. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: fwiw, this is what I get https://godbolt.org/z/KjzasW, though `printVector` is missing. That is the code that produces a runtime error?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Now it does and shows the pointer issue I am having

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I understand, updated with the minimal crashing code

Comment: In the minimal code the error does not show if I remove the printvector call

Comment: I get no crash also with the call https://godbolt.org/z/oe7s8x. What is the complete error message?

Comment: Sorry for the question, @largest_prime_is_463035818 it seems it was indeed a usual out of range access issue at:     for (int i = 0; i < len; i++), with len-1 it is correct. But nevertheless is it 100% safe to reassign the vector passed by reference to a new std::vector<int>?

Comment: dont be sorry for asking a question. Thats what SO is made for ;). Your mistake was to not post a [mcve]. Even though the problem was present already in the first code you posted, not being able to compile and run the code made it difficult to spot it. Nevermind, eventually the question is complete and answerable

Answer (score 2):

The error is in decompress:

```cpp
    int len = todecompress.size();
    int dlen = todecompress[len-1];

    todecompress = std::vector<int>(dlen, 0);

    int di = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (tdc[i] > 0) // there are no 0 values in the compressed vector
        {
            todecompress[di] = tdc[i];
            di++;
        }
```

Actually, there's one excess non-zero value in the compressed vector, that's the original vector length. You're too trying to put it onto the decompressed one but it falls out of bounds already.

Change `len`'s initialization into

```cpp
    int len = todecompress.size() - 1;
```

(for a correct compressed vector it would be non-negative.)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly it. I am sorry that it turns out to be such a basic issue, that's not what stackoverflow is for, but I did not see it. Thanks a lot! Let me mention that this is part of a bigger open source software/partially free time developped so I really appreciated your help.

Comment: Would always prefer unsigned integer semantics here (size_t) as far as possible.

Comment: @Secundi sure, except for converting size values to negative numbers is essential for this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You have some unchecked accesses to vectors which makes your code vulnerable to out-of-bounds access. Don't rely on your logic being correct, but add explicit checks in the code. For example here:

```
    if (tdc[i] > 0) // there are no 0 values in the compressed vector
    {
        std::cout << "error: " << di << " " << todecompress.size() << "\n";
        todecompress[di] = tdc[i];
        di++;
    }
```

I added some debug prints to see index and size. Output I get with your example is:

```
error: 50 50
```

The last valid index in a vector with size 50 is 49. Your code has undefined behavior due to accessing `todecompress` out of bounds. Undefined behavior can lead to crashes at remote places in the code, because `todecompress[di] = tdc[i];` writes to some memory that does not belong to the vector `todecompress`.

Better is (I dont understand the logic completely, so I cannot say if this is correct, but at least it is safer):

```
    if (tdc[i] > 0) // there are no 0 values in the compressed vector
    {
        std::cout << "error: " << di << " " << todecompress.size() << "\n";
        todecompress[di] = tdc[i];
        di++;
        if (di >= todeomcpress.size()) return; // <<-- check for valid index
    }
```

Alternatively use `todecompress.at(di)` instead of `[]` to get a runtime error at the place of the out-of-bounds access instead of crashing elsewhere.

---

> [...] is it 100% safe to reassign the vector passed by reference to a new `std::vector<int>`?

There is no issue with

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& x) {
     x = std::vector<int>(100,0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes it was sadly a stupid out of bounds access but I was convinced it was something bigger... sorry again and thanks for your help!